# Access parallel windows localhost from Android or iPhone's device (Real device) browser

Tags: macos, xamarin.forms, localhost, ip-address, parallels

I am developing an app using Xamarin.Forms. Now I want to connect my mobile app with .Net API project to get datas. I want to connect the mobile project with .Net API project. I have already done following setups:

1. My Parallel Windows IP Config (10.xxx.xx.x) binding is added in
   applicationhost.config file.
2. Opened port in firewall by afding inbound and outbound rule
3. I am successfully accessing Api project url in Mac's browser

**But I am not able to run it in Android mobile's browser (Not Emulator Real Device). I am getting time out error.**

I have done this successfully in normal desktop and this is first time I am using Mac with Windows Parallels.

> MacOS, Windows Parallels, Android, iPhone devices all are connected
>   same network as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed above issue by keeping Static IP address in Windows by disabling "Obtain an IP address automatically" and enabling "Use the following IP address"

I referred following link for how to set static IP:

https://kb.parallels.com/en/112093